# Warnings in xcode: Local declaration hides instance variable

Tags: xcode, ios6

I am writing an app and it all works but I  get a warning with the following simple code which just moves the text box when it is clicked:

```
-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *) observationComment
{
observationComment.frame=CGRectMake(190, 100, 700, 255);
}
```

The warning is:

Local declaration of 'observationComment' hides instance variable

Ant ideas of how to get rid of the warning or should I ignore it?

Comment: the title is way too broad.. it doesn't say anything. 'warnings in Xcode' is as specific as 'trouble in gotham city' (batman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just rename `observationComment` to something else. It has the same name as that of an instance variable. It is best practice, less confusing, to have distinct names so it is clear that it is not the ivar.

Or name it the same way Apple does if this is a delegate callback.

```
-(void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
   textView=CGRectMake(190, 100, 700, 255);
}
```

Comment: Your first part is right, but renaming the method is a bad idea. [`-textViewDidBeginEditing:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextViewDelegate/textViewDidBeginEditing:) is part of the `UITextViewDelegate` protocol. If you remove the colon and argument, you're changing the name of the method, and it will no longer get called by the `UITextView`.

Comment: Exactly. But how then do I get rid of the warning?

Comment: Aha, I see the confusion. The method name is `textViewDidBeginEditing:`, which must remain the same. The argument name `textView` is not part of the method signature, and you can change that to anything you like, as long as it doesn't clash with any other variable names.

Comment: Thank you for your help. All fixed. Very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Rename `observationComment` -- call it `obsCom` or something.  So your method would look like this:

```
-(void) textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *) obsCom
{
    obsCom.frame=CGRectMake(190, 100, 700, 255);
}
```

This will get rid of the warning.